# iPhone showing Connect to iTunes screen when updating to iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios

I have just attempted to update my iPhone 4 to iOS 7. The phone switched itself off after a while and now the phone won't work any more. The screen switched back on with the logo of iTunes and the charger with an arrow pointing to the iTunes logo.

I connected the phone to my Mac and it doesn't recognise my phone at all, asking to restore it to the factory setting. If I do that, would I lose everything on it?

Comment: Have you already tried a hard reset (press the Home-and Power button until the display will show an Apple logo)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will. The same thing happened to mine, everything was wiped out after the restore. Make sure your stuff is backed up.

Answer (score 0):

you can download Tinyumbrella and inside tinyumbrella, select your "restore device" (as it likely is called) and choose to "exit recovery", if this doesn't help, you're probably out of luck. :-/ But I guess you either have an iTunes based or iCloud based backup of your phone, so there is still hope you don't lose all your data